# How to insert an element to a column with array field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a table as follows

```
 CREATE TABLE COMPANY (NO INT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, ID INT[] NOT NULL)
```

Here ID is an array type.

Now when I try to insert an element using

```
INSERT INTO company(no, id)VALUES (4, {1,2,3});
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 3:  VALUES (4, {1,2,3});
```

There is an error.
Could someone help in fixing this?

Comment: `INSERT INTO company(no, id)VALUES (4, '{1,2,3}');`

Answer (score 0):

as per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT

add quotes:

> To write an array value as a literal constant, enclose the element
>   values within curly braces and separate them by commas.

```
t=# INSERT INTO company(no, id)VALUES (4, '{1,2,3}');
INSERT 0 1
```

or use `array[]`:

> The ARRAY constructor syntax can also be used

```
t=# INSERT INTO company(no, id)VALUES (5, array[1,2,3]);
INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. But I am using this from a java program. So I do not know the size of the array. Suppose if I have an array as int arr[]=new int[3]; Then how can I insert the whole array element

Comment: sorry - I don't follow. please provide some code. and better as a different post as I believe the code will be in C?..

Comment: so please post another question with code sample and problem you meet

Comment: My question is, suppose if the array as 100 elements, then I cannot write every element. So I have to store the elements in an array variable and insert the array variable. How can I do this?

Comment: I can' tell without seeing the code and I have no knowledge in C, but if you ask how you pass the C array to postgres array - I believe no how, you have to format it from string. eg, try in postgres: `do $$ begin raise info 'insert into c(in,ar) values(%,array[%])',1,'1,2,3,4,5'; end; $$;`