# JDBC - Inserting an array variable into a PostgreSQL table

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to insert an array variable into the table. The code is shown below

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

class PostgreSQLJDBC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        Statement stmt1 = null;
        int id[] = new int[3];
        int no = 1;
        id[0] = 2;
        id[1] = 14;
        id[2] = 4;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ass2",
                            "postgres", "post");
            c.setAutoCommit(true);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String sql1 = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (NO,ID) "
                    + "VALUES (7, id);";
            stmt1 = c.createStatement();
            stmt1.executeUpdate(sql1);
            stmt1.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
    }
}
```

This code compiles [but gives an PSQLexception.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642761/how-to-insert-an-element-to-a-column-with-array-field)

Could someone please help in fixing this

Comment: `id` is hard-coded in your query. Also consider using `PreparedStatement` with placeholders . Finally, you are creating two `Statement` objects but only using one .

Comment: Many errors on what you are showing: 1. your request is not parameterized; 2. you are not setting your id; 3. what is the type of the ID column of the `Company` table. From what I see, you will have to execute 1 sql query for each of the ID value.

Comment: ID is an integer array.

Comment: ID is an array in your DB ??

Comment: No, it is an array field in the table "COMPANY". Just like INT or VARCHAR, this is INT[]

Comment: @DamCx the OP mean https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [Prepared Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) so you can use [setArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray-int-java.sql.Array-) like this :

But first of all you can't set `int[]` you have to convert it to Array, so you can use :

```
Integer[] id = {2, 14, 4};
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("INTEGER", id);
```

Then create your Prepared Statement and set the array :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (NO, ID) VALUES (?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);) {

    pstmt.setInt(1, 7);   // Set NO
    pstmt.setArray(2, array);  // Set ID

    pstmt.executeUpdate();  // Execute the query
}
```

---

**Note :** please avoid UPPER LETTERS in the name of tables and columns in `PostgreSQL`! This can makes some problems, instead your query should look like :

```
INSERT INTO company (no, id) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Comment: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted into Array.

Comment: Yes, it finally worked with the edit.Spent a lot of time on this .Thanks @YCF_L.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer:

According to these docs: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/arrays.html

it is possible to use some native java arrays as parameter for a prepared statement using the PreparedStatement.setObject method.

So if you are using a primitive int[] instead of Integer[] and setObject instead of setArray it will work as well.

```
int[] ids = {2, 14, 4};
String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST(id_array) VALUES (?)";
try (Connection con = dataSource.getDataSource(); 
     PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql))
{
    statement .setObject(1, ids);  // setObject NOT setArray!
    statement .executeUpdate();
}
```

This is more conventient than calling the createArrayOf method. Especially if you are working with some higher level frameworks spring JDBCTemplate and want to insert String[] arrays.